# When call useState with call by onClick inside the <div> that call userState too. Why it final call useState at main <div>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React call `onClick` that call `useState()` in parent automate when call `useState()` in chide

I would like to close `div` but I cannot, its will always call `onClick` at parent in the final then it always "open"

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Message = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const click = () => {
    console.log("open");
    setMessage("open");
  };

  const close = () => {
    console.log("close");
    setMessage("close");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => click()}>
        {message === "open" ? (
          <div>
            open
            <button onClick={() => close()}>close na</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>not open</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is really hard to read and to make sense of because of the language. Maybe you could improve that.

Comment: Are you seeing the console logs when you click?

Comment: @Nappy -> I agree, my english has some problem anyway there is someone understand and solve it!
backtick -> yes, it duplicate and I will not know in first time due with I don't know root of problem are come from stopPropagation
JaredSmith -> yes, and see they are call parent oncliked but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop event bubbling. Modify your code as follows.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Message = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const click = () => {
    console.log("open");
    setMessage("open");
  };

  const close = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation(); // Stop this click event to trigger click on parent onClick()
    console.log("close");
    setMessage("close");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => click()}>
        {message === "open" ? (
          <div>
            open
            <button onClick={(e) => close(e)}>close na</button> // pass event or use onClick={close}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>not open</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);
```

For more info about bubbling and capturing, read [Event bubbling and capturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture).

Comment: It solve my problem, this is my first time to asking in StackOverflow.... Thank you , thank this web and thank for beautiful world ......

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow :)